# Setting up ViewPager in tab fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I'm having trouble setting up a ViewPager in android ActionBar Tabs.
I'm new to developing apps and try to get everything work by trial-and-error, but this one is quite difficult.

**What I want to have** 
Two actionbar tabs each conatinig a ViewPager with some fragments.

**What I did so far** 
MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // load ActionBar
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_view);
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        tabA = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab A");
        tabB = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab B");
        Fragment fragmentA = new FragmentA();
        Fragment fragmentB = new FragmentB();
        tabA.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentA));
        tabB.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentB));
        actionBar.addTab(tabA);
        actionBar.addTab(tabB);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    class MyTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
        public Fragment frag;

        public MyTabListener(Fragment frag) {
            this.frag = frag;
        }

        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // on tab reselected
        }

        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // need to create own FragmentTransaction cause ActionBar doesn'T support 'android.support.v4'
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fft.replace(R.id.main_fragment_container, frag);
            fft.commit();
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // need to create own FragmentTransaction cause ActionBar doesn'T support 'android.support.v4'
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fft.remove(frag);
            fft.commit();
        }
    }

}
```

FragmentA.class

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_A, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.tabA_pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
    }
}
```

MyPagerAdapter.class

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment f = new Fragment();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            f = LayoutOne.newInstance(null);
            break;
        case 1:
            f = LayoutTwo.newInstance(null);
            break;
        case 2:
            f = LayoutThree.newInstance(null);
            break;
        }
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

LayoutOne.class

```
public class LayoutOne extends Fragment {

    public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
        LayoutOne f = new LayoutOne();
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView root = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_one, null);
        return root;
    }
}
```

**What's the problem** 
The app starts without problems, but the loading of the fragments for tab A seems to be messed up, since the test-text doesn't show.
And when I switch to tab B and then back to tab A, I get FC, saying:
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
    ...
    at FragmentA.onViewCreated
so I guess there's a problem with the ViewPager adapter.

I did some searches, but could not find a working version containing this explicit layout. 
Someone posted a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398525/actionbarsherlock-tabbed-fragments-viewpager-insider-a-fragment) 6 months ago, but without a solution.

What is wrong with my setup?